# Get seen on a local network Docker-Composer

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am currently working on a mobile app that connects to a server instance in docker through a docker-compse instance that can be see by an emulator on my developemnt machine fine, but if I try and use my mobile I can't see the server as it is not on the same network. is there easy way I can set this up to so it can be seen by both my emulator and my mobile at the same time.

my Docker composer setup is

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  node:
    container_name: nodejs
    build: .
    #restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
    extra_hosts:
      - "nodeserver:10.1.1.222"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./db:/data/db
    command: mongod
  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongoExpress
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_USERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PASSWORD: password
    depends_on:
      - mongo
```

I am not a big net-ops guy some so any real help here would appreciated.

Comment: I can see that you already exposing all ports. what error did you get while trying to connect to the server from your mobile ?

Comment: I didn't get an error as I am using Websockets to connect, been try to find a way to get web sockets to send me an error if not connect but nothing seem to work try{
            this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://172.18.0.3:3001');
         } catch(error) {
           Alert.alert(error);
        }

Comment: What is the actual error message?